# How to write a conditioning rule referencing another cell in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

Problem:
I want the color of the cell to change based on the value of another cell.
I have a cell (B1) with MTD capture that is calculated by taking asset A and dividing it by Asset B in different cells.
If my return for the month is positive(value is positive) according to cell A1 then B1 is green. But if I lost some money(value is negative) in cell A1 how do I make B1 turn red?

I feel like it's such a basic question but can't figure it out.

Comment: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: Yes, it's a pretty basic question but everyone starts somewhere and sometimes things are not as obvious as one would wish. Follow the heading "Use custom formulas with conditional formatting" in the link that @User24601 provided. You need two rules (both use Custom formula) for the formatting of B1: 1=Profit (=A1>=0) and 2=Loss (=A1<0). If you can successfully build your conditional formatting rules, consider writing an answer to your own question. Others will surely benefit in the future.